# Как сделать проще код

Tags: php

Есть последовательность действий, как упростить код?

```
<?php
$arr = array(
  '100'=>'full',
  '101'=>'low',
  '108'=>'reload',
  '109'=>'Karl',
);


$arrs = array(
  '0'=>'109',
);

foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
  # code...
  if ($arrs[0] == $key) {
    foreach ($arr as $key1 => $value1) {
      # code...
      if ($value1=='full') {
        $arr[$key1] = $value;
        $arr[$arrs[0]] = $value1; //1 этап

        foreach ($arr as $key2 => $value2) {
          # code...
          if ($value2 == 'low') {
            $arr[$arrs[0]] = $value2;
            $arr[$key2] = $value1;  // 2 этап
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

print_r($arr);
```

```
Array // 1 этап
(
  [100] => Karl
  [101] => low
  [108] => reload
  [109] => full
)
Array // 2 этап
(
  [100] => Karl
  [101] => full
  [108] => reload
  [109] => low
)
```

Comment: а вы не хотите обычным языком объяснить сначала, что делает ваш код, или что вы думаете он делает.

Comment: это dram, в упрорщенном виде, изобретаю велосипед) пока так потом чуть сложнее) а так он делает последовательную замену ключей оставляя значения не тронутыми

Comment: давайте еще раз про обычный язык. у вас есть исходный массив, что вы хотите с ним делать.

Comment: немногго поправил может поможет для обьяснения

Comment: есть бутыли с водой полный пустой и на перезаправке . Карл приносит пустой бутыль я ему возвращяю полный, ну теперь с массивом) бутыли пронумерованы вот вся хитрость

Comment: я по вашему примеру вижу, что крал стал на первом месте, а в full и low меняются местами. вы пока адекватно суть проблемы не изложите ответа здесь не получите.

Comment: @teran допустим ты выдаёшь бутыли с водой я приношу 109 бутыль, твои действия .. дашь мне полную 100,  у тебя останется 109  в массиве ты её поменяешь с full на low, я всё меняю только перестоновкой ключей ) как упростить код теперь) типичный барабан рулетка

Comment: Карлу отдали 100-ю, 109 - пустая.казалось бы reload станет full, low - reload?

Comment: а можно оформить задачу получше: цель? задача? входные и выходные данные и только потом как оптимизировать код получше чем сейчас

Comment: @splash58 reload пока не трогаем) водовоз ещё не приехал ))))

Comment: Тогда кто наполнил low?

Comment: @splash58 это барабан играют только левые части, запас воды же есть изночально )))

Comment: @splash58 приедет водовоз заберёт бутыли какието отдаст ключи поменяются, а база значения то все остануться

Comment: а в массиве может быть несколько элементов с одинаковым  соcтояникем full, например?

Comment: я написал ответ, посмотрите

Comment: гляну...........

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял вашу логику

```
function array_swap_values(&$arr, $new) {
    $low  = array_keys($arr, 'low')[0];
    $full = array_keys($arr, 'full')[0];
    $arr[$low] = 'full';
    $arr[$full] = $arr[$new];
    $arr[$new] = 'low';

}

array_swap_values($arr, $arrs[0]);
print_r($arr);

Array
(
    [100] => Karl
    [101] => full
    [108] => reload
    [109] => low
)
```

Comment: а сюда логи последовательности можно приклеить?

Comment: а если на русском?

Comment: ну типа в строки записать последовательность действий функции

Comment: типа, `echo "$low: {$arr[$low]}  => full";`

Comment: т.е пришёл, отдали, заменили на складе итд

Comment: то что я написал в комменте - оно?

Comment: ну $low это номер ) чтоб видно было file put contents

Comment: $file='log.txt';
file_put_contents($file, $arrs[0].'-'.$value1."\r\n", FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);  у себя бы так сделал

Comment: в функции происходят изменения `$arr[$low] = 'full';`  вот такая строка `"$low: {$arr[$low]} => full";` говорит, что  у ключа  $low значение  поменялось с $arr[$low] на full и т.д.

Comment: $key1.'-'.$value."\r\n"  мне человека выципить с его новой бутылью

Comment: Это вот оно `$arr[$full] = $arr[$new];`  $arr[$new] получил бутыль номер $full

Comment: Ок, освобожусь посмотрю)) может и сгадим)

Comment: вот так в лог написал    low -получил бутыль номер- 100

file_put_contents($file, $arr[$new].' -получил бутыль номер- '.$full."\r\n", FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX); а надо Karl -получил бутыль номер- 100

Comment: а всё поменял на $arr[$full]

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/385ace7fbfea4e24beaf2ea1e318fb4e1ed56ecb